# Sum in subquery for a group of numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, max, min

We are trying to get a combined table where we also try to sum the volume.

Dateset right now:

```
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| Voorziening | BSN | Begindatum | Einddatum  | Volume | Product |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1000        |  1  |  1-1-2017  | 31-1-2017  |   50   |   AAAA  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1200        |  1  |  1-2-2017  | 31-3-2017  |   200  |   AAAA  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1250        |  1  |  1-4-2017  | 10-4-2017  |   90   |   AAAA  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1111        |  2  |  4-1-2017  | 10-1-2017  |   4    |   AABB  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1345        |  2  |  11-1-2017 | 29-1-2017  |   80   |   AABB  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 2000        |  1  |  10-1-2017 | 31-1-2017  |   90   |   CCCC  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 2190        |  1  |  1-2-2017  | 31-12-2017 |   100  |   CCCC  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
```

What I want to achieve

```
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| Voorziening | BSN | Begindatum | Einddatum  | Volume | Product |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1000        |  1  |  1-1-2017  | 10-4-2017  |   340  |  AAAA   |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 2000        |  1  |  10-1-2017 | 31-12-2017 |   190  |  CCCC   |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1111        |  2  |  4-1-2017  | 29-1-2017  |   84   |  AABB   |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
```

What i've got so for is the folowwing query:

```
SELECT  min(b.Voorziening) as voorzieningsnummer
,a.BSN
,min(b.Begindatum) as mindatum
,MAX(b.Einddatum) AS maxdatum
,a.Productcode
,
(SELECT sum(Volume)
FROM Voorziening
)as totaal
FROM Voorziening a
INNER JOIN Voorziening b
ON a.BSN = b.BSN
AND a.Productcode = b.Productcode
GROUP BY a.BSN, a.Productcode
```

The result is gives me is this:

```
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+
| Voorziening | BSN | Begindatum | Einddatum  | Volume |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+
| 1000        |  1  |  1-1-2017  | 10-4-2017  |   424  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+
| 1111        |  2  |  4-1-2017  | 29-1-2017  |   424  |
+-------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+
```

You guys can help me to get the sum right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any reason to use `JOIN`. you can use aggregate function directly.

You can try this.

```
SELECT  min(a.Voorziening) as voorzieningsnummer
        ,a.BSN
        ,min(a.Begindatum) as mindatum
        ,MAX(a.Einddatum) AS maxdatum
        ,a.Productcode
        ,SUM(a.Volume) Volume 
FROM Voorziening a
GROUP BY a.BSN, a.Productcode
```

Comment: There is a reason, because BSN and Productcode has to be equal. There a lots of records where this isn't the case. The examples are just not in my dataset on top.

Comment: Could you provide more sample for your question? 
From your description it should be work

Comment: When you use group by on those columns it will make a group result by them.

Comment: @miltenburger My query is working in your edit sample data .https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c46093e14196d87178b7f505f951a9d

Comment: damn I made a stupid mistake, yours is working fine! Thx m8

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server 2008 or above version then just go ahead with `PARTITION BY`

```
SUM(Volume)over(Partition by Product order by Voorziening,another,another)
```